# Create 3D models on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I want to implement an android application that has the capability to create a 3D model/object. (Not a 3D model Viewer but a creator) 
I have worked on unity3d modelling where I can create 3D objects and can be rendered later on the android application as in the form of assets. 
Now I want to create 3D objects directly on android.I have looked around openGL but couldn't find any tutorials or standard examples where I can create a 3D object from scratch on android application.
So my question is, what are the best procedure to create 3D objects on android?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES is an API to render your 3d model and does not have all the functionalities for creating or modelling a 3d mesh.

You can start with some Mesh Library (CGAL and OpenMesh) which allow you to store & modify 3d mesh efficiently. To allow user to modify 3d mesh, you can start with simple geometries like Cube or Sphere. Then for every action by the user, you have to move or add the triangles of your mesh using the library.